# Невозможно подключиться к Google Cloud по SSH

Tags: windows, облако, google-cloud

Система `Windows 10`.

Пытаюсь подключиться к удалённой машине, размещённой на `Google Cloud` по `SSH` *(через браузер)*. В результате падает ошибка:

```
Connection Failed
We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22.
```

На сервере есть правило, разрешающее доступ по `SSH` *(TCP:22)*.

Не могу понять в чём проблема. С остальными машинами нет никаких проблем с доступом *(остальные машины на `Linux`, находятся в той же сети)*. Брэндмауэр я отключил, но никаких улучшений не произошло. Как я могу решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему, установив `Google Cloud SDK Shell`, через неё подключение прошло без каких-либо проблем.